# max limit of data fullcalendar can hold

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, fullcalendar

Is there a max amount of data that a bootstrap fullcalendar can hold. it seems to crash after 525 entries. It was working fine till it reached this limit.

It threw an error:

```
Error: {"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}
```

I am binding my data dynamically.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var events = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Dashboard.aspx/GetEvents",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data.d, function (i, v) {
                    events.push({
                        title: v.Title,
                        start: moment(v.VCStartTime),
                        end: v.VCEndTime != null ? moment(v.VCEndTime) : null
                    });
                })
                GenerateCalendar(events);//binds data to calendar
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
            //error: function (error) {
            //    alert('failed');
            //}
        })
```

Asp.net code for fetching data

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<events> GetEvents()
{

    DataSet ds = new APIProcedure().ByProcedure("calendar_sp", new string[] { "key" },
       new string[] { "getvalueForCalendar" }, "USPADDSETTING");

    return ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(datarow =>
    new events()
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(datarow["Id"]),
        Title = Convert.ToString(datarow["Title"]),
        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(datarow["Date"]),
        StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(datarow["StartTime"]),
        EndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(datarow["EndTime"]),
    }
    ).ToList();

}

public class events
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There's no documented limit. You could perhaps raise an issue on the fullCalendar GitHub site if you think there's an internal bug. I have heard of people loading more than that though. What specific error did you encounter?

Comment: P.S. 525 is still quite a lot of events though. Do you really need to load all these? I notice from your code you don't seem to be sending anything to the server to restrict the events to a specific period of time. In fact you're pre-loading the events and then generating the calendar. The recommended approach is to tell fullCalendar the source of your events, and then it will run your AJAX call each time it needs new events - it will give you a start and end date to pass to the server, and you can use those to return only events which are actually needed in the current view and date range.

Comment: ... see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function for more details. This will be more efficient than trying to load 500+ events all at once, especially if many of them will never actually be looked at by theuser.

Comment: @ADyson i will raise the issue on github just to see if there is a bug.  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function seems to be the right way to handle it. Thanks

Comment: Ok good idea. BTW that error message looks more like something went wrong with your asp.net code, not fullCalendar.

Comment: I feel like this has nothing do do with either asp.net or c# so perhaps those tags could be removed?

Comment: @ADyson asp.net code is pretty straight forward. i am calling database and fetching values. it is working fine till 525 entries. Changing my approach now the way you suggested.

Comment: That's a good idea. It's possible your .NET code timed out, or some JSON serialisation size limit was reached or something like that. Impossible for me to know for sure, you'd have to check your error logs and/or do some other debugging. The error only says it failed, it doesn't say why. But anyway yes if you do the approach of only loading smaller sets of events based on the current date range, then that kind of problem should never arise anyway.

Comment: P.S. I notice in the .NET code you're creating a structure with Date, StartTime, EndTime as separate properties. This means you then have to have JavaScript code at the other end to transform it into the format that fullCalendar needs. Since you're creating a custom data structure anyway, why not just write the .NET code so that it outputs it in the correct format to begin with? This would save some extra code and processing. And then you could use the simpler JSON feed technique (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) to link it to fullCalendar directly without the extra function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        contentHeight: 400,
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        eventLimit: true,
        eventColor: '#87c9f0',
        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {//instead of getting all the data at once get data for visible part of calendar.

            var Date1 = new Date(start);
            let newdate = JSON.stringify(Date1);
            newStartdate = newdate.slice(1, 11);

            var Date2 = new Date(end);
            let newdate2 = JSON.stringify(Date2);
            newEnddate = newdate2.slice(1, 11);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{ 'StartDate': '" + newStartdate + "', 'EndDate': '" + newEnddate + "' }",//send data to code behind and get data according to start and end date
                url: "Dashboard.aspx/GetEvents",
                success: function (data) {
                    var events = [];
                    $.each(data.d, function (i, v) {
                        events.push({
                            title: v.Title,
                            start: moment(v.VCStartTime),
                            end: v.VCEndTime != null ? moment(v.VCEndTime) : null
                        });
                    })
                    callback(events);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
            })
        }
```